# C++ - Calling a constructor other than the default when an object is instantiated in another class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Feel free to edit the title I'm not sure how to phrase this.

I'm trying to figure out how to call a class's constructor other than the default when it is instantiated in another class. What I mean is this...

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){cout << "i get this default constructor when I create a B" << endl;}
    A(int i){cout << "this is the constructor i want when I create a B" << endl;}
};

class B
{
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    B *ptr = new B;
    return 0;
}
```

I've done some searching but I don't see a way to do what I want. I thought maybe in B's declaration I could do `A a(5)` but that doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Just a note: that `B *ptr = new B;` can be replaced by the safer `B obj;`. You won't have to free any memory. If you still need a pointer, consider `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ calling non-default constructor as member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643548/c-calling-non-default-constructor-as-member)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that with a [constructor initialization list](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) (you might also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists) and others similar to it).

This means that you will have to manually write a constructor for `B`:

```
class B
{
    A a;

    public: B() : a(5) {}
};
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/sH4T0)**.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I like your example tool it's pretty cool.